# Display different pages at same url according to where user is coming from

Tags: django, web-services

I would like to display different landing pages in different situations, according to the url the user is coming from. The urls they are coming from are not part of our website.

Is it possible (in django) to do this without having to have a unique url for each landing page?

Comment: Are the URL they're coming from part of your website or are they random parts of the internet?

Comment: @Delyan The urls are random parts of the internet

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is the way to go then (see Tim's answer) but 1) treat it as you would treat any untrusted user input, 2) it will not always be present and 3) it might contain the previous page's GET query (depends on browser last I had to use it), so you might want to try and filter that out, depending on your application (I needed to, for analytics purposes).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to look at the referer header in the HTTP Request.  You can do this by checking `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` in your view function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

From there, you can return a different template while maintaining the same url as it's being handled by the same view function.

Answer (score -1):

Within the view you can decide what to do based on `request.get_host()`.

eg. a simple example might be

```
def myview(request):
    host = request.get_host()
    if host == 'example.com':
        context['title'] = 'one thing'
        ....
    else:
        context['title'] = 'another thing'
        ....
    ....
```

Comment: `get_host()` returns `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` or `HTTP_HOST`. Nothing to do with where the user is coming from.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "coming from", it could well mean which particular DNS is farwarding their request (eg. what the host name is), but then I guess it's more likely they mean which page the user has clicked on to get there. the problem is ambiguity in the question, not an error in my answer.

Comment: What does "DNS forwarding their request" even mean? . `get_host()` is useful for reconstructing the URL that the user (or frontend server) requested. On most installations, I'm willing to bet that it's `127.0.0.1:<some_port>` or the site's domain name, depending on frontend config.

Comment: The user "requests" a url then the DNS server forwards that request to the site. If host_name is the same for most sites, why has ALLOWED_HOSTS become required in 1.5.4??? The point is that it's not constant or unimportant, you might want to constrict it, OR you might want to make decisions based on it: you have two URLs (and therefore DNSs records) for your site, eg. uk.mysite.com and usa.mysite.com, and want to show different sites for each.

Comment: The sentence "DNS server forwards that request to the site" is wrong. A DNS server resolves a domain to an IP address. The client is the one contacting the IP address and sending the appropriate `Host:` header. I'm not saying that you can't be making decisions based on `get_host`, you obviously can and you've listed good use cases for that (btw ALLOWED_HOSTS is required solely as a security measure) However, the question asked how to change the landing page based on the URL the user is coming *from*, not the URL the user is requesting. As such, your answer is incorrect and Tim's is correct.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I misinterpreted the question. With respect to the host, it may be possible to set the host in the header to anything but the great majority of your website users have it set based on the URL they required and therefore the DNS which resolved their request, which is why I said DNS. In short I was too hasty and wrong.

Comment: FYI, the `Host` header is not optional. The browser sets it automatically and it's the plumbing that allows multiple websites, with multiple domains to be hosted on a single IP address.

Comment: But it is forged by a lot of bots (presumably thinking it will help them find a vulnerability) which is why I said the 'majority' not all.